# Wykobi - Error: Explicit instantiation shall not use ‘inline’ specifier [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, overlap

I am trying to make / compile [wykobi](http://www.wykobi.com) library (computational geometry) using the given makefile, but I keep getting the error:

> error: explicit instantiation shall not use ‘inline’ specifier [-fpermissive]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment. Have you considered using CGAL instead?

Comment: I have added the `C++` tag to your question. If I was wrong, please feel free to revert.

Comment: What compiler and version? Also, have you tried to open that file ad remove that `inline`.

Comment: I suspect it will compile if you add -fpermissive to the compiler command line.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the compiler flags set in the makefile from command line:

```
make OPTIONS_LIBS="-fpermissive -O3 -o" OPTIONS="-fpermissive -O3 -o"
```